# Numeric types and row size in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-design, data-modeling

I have a user table structured like this:

- id MEDIUMINT(7),
- username VARCHAR(15)

Would it technically be faster if I changed it to this instead:

- id MEDIUMINT(5),
- username VARCHAR(15)

I'm confused because even though the total row length in terms of characters and digits would be shorter, I assume the number of bytes used would be the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm confused because even though the total row length in terms of characters and digits would be shorter, I assume the number of bytes used would be the same.

You're correct - the number of digits specified does *not* change the number of bytes that a MEDIUMINT column will use to hold the value.  Effectively, there's no speed performance.

Reference:

- [Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html)

Answer (score 3):

The argument after MEDIUMINT makes no difference to its storage or the range of values it supports.  It's only a hint for display width.  Mostly this is relevant only when you use the ZEROFILL option.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (num MEDIUMINT(7) ZEROFILL);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1234);
SELECT num FROM foo;

0001234
```

MEDIUMINT is always three bytes.

Answer (score 1):

No, it would be no faster. The number after MEDIUMINT is just the display width. It affects only the way in which query results are displayed in some contexts.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a display width. If you use MEDIUMINT(5), it does not use small resource than just using MEDIUMINT. Thanks you for your question. I have a same question.

Reference:
[12.2.5 Numeric Type Attributes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html)

> The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be
> stored in the column. Nor does it prevent values wider than the column
> display width from being displayed correctly. For example, a column
> specified as SMALLINT(3) has the usual SMALLINT range of -32768 to
> 32767, and values outside the range permitted by three digits are
> displayed in full using more than three digits.